Dynamically operate on column (inside :=)
I have the below data table
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(col1 = 1:3
                 , col2 = 2:4
                 )

I would like to dynamically operate on a column, whose column name is stored in the below object:
metric <- 'col2'

but the below failed
df[, `:=` (col1 = col1 - 1
           , as.name(metric) = as.numeric(get(metric))
           )
   ]

error:
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df[, `:=` (col1 = col1 - 1
           , as.name(metric) ="

I would like to operate on col1 and whatever column whose name is stored in metric in one call.
Are there any methods other than the below (which works)
df[, c('col1', metric) := .(col1 - 1
                            , as.numeric(get(metric))
                            )
   ]


Using get() in data.table has been retired. I think the proper way to do this these days is using env.
I'll add 2 to the assignment so we can see it is modifying something:
df[, `:=`(
    col1 = col1 - 1,
    col = as.numeric(col) + 2
), env = list(col = metric)][]

#     col1  col2
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     0     4
# 2:     1     5
# 3:     2     6

Or using let(), which is an alias for `:=` as suggested by Roland in the comments:
df[,
    let(
        col1 = col1 - 1,
        col = as.numeric(col) + 2
    ),
    env = list(col = metric)
] # same result


I'd prefer let if using the functional form.

SamR, I see. I'm falling behind in my data.table knowledge.
Thanks for link. Will read up.
Roland, would you be able to show us your method please?

@Roland  I don't - it makes my brain think I'm using JS :)

@SweepyDodo Roland is talking about replacing := with let, which is an alias. See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/assign.html

data.table has been updated with so much freshness since the first time I started to learn it, and glad to see the new features through your great answer, cheers!

Alias. Got you.
Good to see the usuals on here and the continual progress with the package
Am curious, what do we mean by 'retired'?
Discouraged to use?
Because get still works

@SweepyDodo the devs say about get(), mget() and eval() Those interfaces should now be considered retired and we recommend using the new env argument, instead. I would take that to mean that they may or may not work in all instances, but the package will be optimised for env, and that the under-the-hood speed up that you get like fast grouping operations should be expected to work using env and not necessarily with the other approaches.
